# How to make normal content look scrollable (like a UITableView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller with a few labels and switches inside of it. Is there any way to make the whole view look "scrollable" like how UITableViewCells look. Like even if there isn't enough content to need it to be scrollable I want that interactive gesture that UITableViewCells have. The whole point of this is to make all the pages on my app feel similar. Is there any way to add that same "scrolling" or "dynamic" feeling to the normal view?

Edit: A link to show what I mean
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3VS.jpg

Here is the code where I connect the scroll view and I am making it "scrollable"

```
class ThemesViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var spacer: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var overrideThemeDesc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var overrideSystemTheme: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var overrideThemeToggle: UISwitch!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lightButton: RadioButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var darkButton: RadioButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lightText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var darkText: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var appearanceLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var interactiveView: UIScrollView!
    
    let themeOverrideDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        interactiveView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
// Rest of My Code
}
```

And here is a picture of the storyboard with the scroll view selected (to show it has custom class UIScrollView): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoXJQ.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "interactive gesture"?

Comment: You mean embed your content into a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: add an empty view at the bottom that overflows screen size - that way scroll will have to appear

Comment: When you look at a UITableView if a user swipes up or down on a cell it'll move up or down with the finger (even if the cells all fit on the page). That's what I mean by interactive gesture. I tried looking into UIScrollViews but all that did was scroll down. I don't actually need a scrolling feature (to see content that won't fit on the screen). I just need the interactive gesture described above. I don't need a scroll bar either.

Comment: then you didn't really explain what you need... do you mean "pull to refresh"?

Comment: here, I edited in a link to show what I mean. The example I gave is instagram. You can see how the view scrolls up and down with my finger.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other example or give suggestions before downvoting please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your view into a UIScrollView and then set

```swift
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

so that you get that scrolling effect even if the content is not large enough to be scrolled.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure what it was called. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, actually I've started getting this error using that. The error is: Exception: "-[UIView setAlwaysBounceVertical:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102704950". I don't know what's wrong as it was just working earlier and I'm using it in the exact same way and now it won't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ShamitSurana can you post some of your code? The error means that something is trying to set alwaysBounceVertical on a `UIView` but `UIView` in general has no such instance variable, only `UIScrollView` has that.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post to include some of that code

Comment: I edited my post to include the code and screenshot of the storyboard